# How to deal with elimination of duplicate logic vs. cost of complexity increase?

Tags: c#

I just wrote some code that is very representative of a recurring theme (in my coding world lately): repeated logic leads to an instinct to eliminate duplication which results in something that is more complex the tradeoff seems wrong to me (the examples of the negative side aren't worth posting - but this is probably the 20th console utility I've written in the past 12 months).

I'm curious if I'm missing some techniques or if this is really just on of those "experience tells you when to do what" type of issues.

Here's the code... I'm tempted to leave it as is, even though there will be about 20 of those if-blocks when I'm done.

```
static void Main(string[] sargs)
{
    try
    {
        var urls = new DirectTrackRestUrls();
        var restCall = new DirectTrackRestCall();
        var logger = new ConsoleLogger();
        Args args = (Args)Enum.Parse(typeof(Args), string.Join(",", sargs));
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.Campaigns))
        {
            var getter = new ResourceGetter(logger, urls.ListAdvertisers, restCall);
            restCall.UriVariables.Add("access_id", 1);
            getter.GotResource += new ResourceGetter.GotResourceEventHandler(getter_GotResource);
            getter.GetResources();
            SaveResources();
        }
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.Advertisers))
        {
            var getter = new ResourceGetter(logger, urls.ListAdvertisers, restCall);
            restCall.UriVariables.Add("access_id", 1);
            getter.GotResource += new ResourceGetter.GotResourceEventHandler(getter_GotResource);
            getter.GetResources();
            SaveResources();
        }
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.CampaignGroups))
        {
            var getter = new ResourceGetter(logger, urls.ListCampaignGroups, restCall);
            getter.GotResource += new ResourceGetter.GotResourceEventHandler(getter_GotResource);
            getter.GetResources();
            SaveResources();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
```

Comment: As phrased this question would appear to be better asked on Stack Overflow, however, with a change of wording ("How can I/should I improve this code") then it would be suitable for Code Review. As it stands there's a very good chance it will get closed here.

Comment: I realized that after I saw the answers... but I did get a good answer, for my purposes I'm happy (although it may not have served the collective in the optimal way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not something like...

```
static void Main(string[] sargs)
{
    try
    {
        var urls = new DirectTrackRestUrls();
        var restCall = new DirectTrackRestCall();
        var logger = new ConsoleLogger();
        Args args = (Args)Enum.Parse(typeof(Args), string.Join(",", sargs));
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.Campaigns))
        {
            GetAndSaveResources(urls.ListAdvertisers, true);
        }       
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.Advertisers))
        {
            GetAndSaveResources(urls.ListAdvertisers, true);
        }
        if (args.HasFlag(Args.CampaignGroups))
        {
            GetAndSaveResources(urls.ListCampaignGroups, false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}

void GetAndSaveResources(IList list, bool setAccessId) {
    var getter = new ResourceGetter(logger, list, restCall);
    if (setAccessId)
        restCall.UriVariables.Add("access_id", 1);
    getter.GotResource += new ResourceGetter.GotResourceEventHandler(getter_GotResource);
    getter.GetResources();
    SaveResources();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't currently have proper variable scoping...the getter should probably come out of the function, and get passed in.

Comment: i've never seen the function keyword in c# - is that real?

Comment: hey I just wanted to thank you - i re-wrote it your way and it's better - i had been going down the road of using containers to auto construct objects, but your DRY style is the piece of the puzzle I was not considering

Comment: @Gabriel, ya, get rid of that `function`.  I've been coding too much in javascript lately.

Answer (score 3):

> "I'm curious if I'm missing some techniques or if this is really just on of those "experience tells you when to do what" type of issues.".

There are tools that will show you where you've duplicated code.  Look into Atomiq or CodeRush if you're using Visual Studio.

Aside from that, Chad's reply looks to have refactored your code in a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) manner.  You should be obsessive about not copying and pasting code because it causes huge maintainability issues.

Comment: Yes, every time you copy/paste in code, it should be cause for pause.